# ORA-29283: invalid file operation: unexpected "LFI" error

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I was working on upgrade Oracle from 11g to 19c recently, I upgrade my laptop from Win7 to Win10 and finally installed Oracle successfully, then I create tablespace and tables, now I can access them from both sqlplus/plsql.

We have an old system developed by asp.net web form, it use System.Data.OracleClient, after upgraded to Win10, it doesn't work so I use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client instead of it.

There has a function to export some data from Oracle and we use "UTL_FILE.FOPEN('BIAO_DIR', v_file_name, 'W');" command, however, it's not worked, after some test I found this command worked well when I use oracle's self directory.

If I replace BIAO_DIR with ORACLE_HOME, this command will run correctly. My user is CODEDATA, I wonder how can fix this, thanks.

[Query the directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7qZp.png)

[Query the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inp7p.png)

Comment: Have you tried granting Windows directory read and write privileges to the relevant user? (There are several different ways to setup the user accounts with Oracle on Windows, you may need to grant privileges to more than just your normal user.)

Answer (score 1):

GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY biao_dir TO userName;